# NavigationView Selected Item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigationview

I have this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
            android:title="Search Location" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fav"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
            android:title="Favorites" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_recent"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_route"
            android:title="Recent Location" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_place"
            android:title="Route" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Others">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="About" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

But when selecting the nav_settings,
the item is not check.
The item should be check just like the other items above.
This is my code on setting the item checked.
The fragment will just work fine.
but the selector on the nav_settings didn't work..

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            Fragment fragment = null;

            Class fragmentClass;
            switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentMap.class;
                    setTitle("Map");
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_search:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentSearchLoc.class;
                    Global.setCurrentItem =2;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_recent:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentSearchLoc.class;
                    Global.setCurrentItem =0;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_fav:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentSearchLoc.class;
                    Global.setCurrentItem =1;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_route:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentRoute.class;
                    setTitle("Routing");
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentSettings.class;
                    setTitle("Settings");
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmentClass = FragmentMap.class;
            }

            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

            drawer
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            drawer.closeDrawers();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nesting items like your code is allowed.

If you do like below, it may work:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
         android:title="Settings" />
     <item
         android:id="@+id/nav_about"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
         android:title="About" />
</group>
```

Comment: Will i still be able to add title if I do this?